# how to display the stored data in just the way it was formatted by user?

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea as an input in my HTML form. When any user writes something like following (I am trying to point out the line breaks):

```
The quick brown fox jumps **over**
the lazy dog
```

And when it is stored into database and I retrieved it and echo it appears without the line breaks, it looks like following:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Could you please tell me how to display the stored data in just the way it was formatted by the user?

When I display data I just retrieve information from database just the usual way and then just echo it like this-- `<? echo $value_text ;?>`

Thanks in Advance :0

Comment: nl2br() is the usual way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($value_text));
```

[`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) - [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the line breaks don't exist?

If you are using this on a website, you may need to replace the line break with a 
 tag.

```
echo nl2br($data);
```

http://us.php.net/nl2br

Or you can alternatively wrap the text in `<pre>` tag's

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the text in an `nl2br()` function like this: `<? echo nl2br($value_text);?>`. This will convert all new lines into `<br>` tags.

When your page loads, the php echo gets interpreted as html. As you know, new lines in HTML don't affect the layout of a page. This is why you need every line break converted into a `<br>` tag.